# Performance overhead of using IoC containers with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, ninject, autofac, castle

I have an MVC3 application that I hope will be serving a large number of user requests. I would like to use an IoC container but don't want it to slow down the performance of my application.

I read that I shouldn't be concerned as the only overhead is at the time of initialization.  However for an MVC3 application is this not EVERY time a user requests a new web page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not every time the user requests a page. The IoC container should be configured once for the lifetime of the application (in your global Application_Start event handler, for instance) and then shouldn't require any additional configuration while the application runs.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Now I believe I don't need to look at those charts showing relative performance.